Github Actions Subfolder
Hi I have a project with this structure and I am having a Github actions error that I cannot figure out. The unit test that I want to run are inside the app folder. It's vite project with Vue3
.github - folder
api - backend 
app - ui

When the Github actions run this is the error :
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/fss/fss/package.json'

This is my workflow yml file. Thank You
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test-frontend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./app
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
          cache: pnpm

      - name: Install
        run: pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Typecheck
        run: pnpm run typecheck

      - name: Install
        run: pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Test
        run: pnpm run test:unit

